# Elevation along a path

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-visualization

I am using the Google Maps API to show the elevation along a path :
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/elevation-paths
On the y-axis, the elevation is shown.
I would like to add a scale on the x-axis to show the distance to the initial point of the path.
Any idea on how to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Could put your attempts so far in jsfiddle or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the options for a column chart, the type used in the elevation path example. https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/columnchart

You would have to build the data array with a distances column and then use that as a  chart option for hAxis.